# UML class diagram static method dependecy

Tags: java, static, uml

I have 3 classes: Class A and Class B. They have variables. Class C has no variables, but only static methods that class A and B use.

My first question is how do I represent this using a UML class diagram? I was thinking of using a dashed line arrow ( -----> ) from A to C and from B to C with the "usesStatically" message on the arrow. Is this correct?

Also, my second question is do I represent the main() methods of my A and B classes? That's the only ones they have, and they use methods from C inside; C doesn't have a main() and only contains statics methods.

Code is like this:

```
    Class A  {
      main()
      {
      C.method1();  
      }
   }
```

class B:

```
Class B{
    main()
    {
    C.method2();    
    }
}
```

class C:

```
   Class C{
method1(); 
method2();
}
```

Third, my last question: in my UML class diagram, would method1() belong in class A or class C, or in both? Similarly, would method2() belong in B, C or both?

Comment: This may help http://www.tutorialspoint.com/uml/uml_class_diagram.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Class Diagram is a **structure diagram**, and thus you are not interested in the way particular methods call each other, rather you focus on capturing classes and their relations. So instead of saying "instance of `A` calls `C.method1`", you simply say that `A` uses `C`.

[image]

Adding `main()` is questionable. If such method makes sense in your domain then include it, if the only reason is that that's the entry point in your language, you should probably omit it as it doesn't add value to the diagram.

If you want to capture the actual method calls between the classes, UML has **behavior diagrams** for that, here namely

Communication Diagram, and

[image]

Sequence Diagram

[image]